# PHP : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end

Tags: php

I keep having a syntax error, unexpected $end.

I checked my code, but there's nothing wrong. I checked all the opening and closing brackets. What seems to be the problem?

My code:

```
<?php
setcookie('name',$_POST['name']);

setcookie('lname',$_POST['lname']);

setcookie('add',$_POST['add']);

setcookie('age',$_POST['age']);

setcookie('contact',$_POST['contact']);

setcookie('email',$_POST['email']);

setcookie('user',$_POST['user']);

setcookie('pass',$_POST['pass']);


$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("nnx",$con);

$tbl=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE `username` =         '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user'])."'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($tbl))
{

if($_POST['user']==$row['username'])
{
    header("location: /register.php?codeErr2=1");
        die;
}

$name=$_POST['name'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];
$add=$_POST['add'];
$age=$_POST['age'];
$contact=$_POST['contact'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$user=$_POST['user'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];

if(($name!="")&&($lname!="")&&($add!="")&&($age!="")&&($contact!="")&&($email!="")&&    ($user!="")&&($pass!=""))
{
    $value=mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablename(name, lastname, address, age, contact,     email, username, password)
VALUES     ('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['lname']."','".$_POST['add']."','".$_POST['age']."','".$_PO    ST['contact']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['user']."','".$_POST['pass']."')");
}

else
{
    header("location: /register.php?codeErr=1");    
}


?>

<html>
<body bgcolor="green">
<center>

<h1>Welcome! These are the offered products</h1>
<table border="1" width="1000" height="500" bgcolor="yellow">
<tr>
<th>Product</th>
<th>Description</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>GARLIQUE</td>
<td>GARLIQUE
The All Natural Dietary Supplement
Produced from fresh garlic

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Right-CEE</td>
<td>Right-CEE (Sodium Ascorbate) …

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>OLEIA</td>
<td>OLEIA CAPSULE
No More Pain, Heart to Gain


</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<form name="product" action="order.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Order">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The answer is the same as all these http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PHP+%3A+Parse+error%3A+syntax+error%2C+unexpected+%24end - You have mis-matched brackets. Look at the related column.

Comment: There are so many problems with this code. Please read up on security: http://docforge.com/wiki/Web_application/Security

Answer (score 6):

you forgot to close `while`:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($tbl))
{

if($_POST['user']==$row['username'])
{
    header("location: /register.php?codeErr2=1");
        die;
}
}//<---- here
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not closing the brace after your `while` loop.

Indenting your code makes this sort of thing a lot easier to spot!

Answer (score 1):

You have an opening brace `{` on the `while` loop, but you don't seem to have a corresponding closing brace.